# On the gradient of a left-invariant metric on a Lie group

Tags: riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a matrix Lie group equipped with a left-invariant metric $\langle .,. \rangle$. Let $\xi \in \mathfrak{g}$. Define the function $f(g):=\langle \log(g), \xi\rangle \in \mathbb{R}$ for $g \in B \subset G$, $B$ is a geodesic ball centered at the identity matrix $I$ with radius less than the manifold injectivity radius (making $f$ well-defined). Since $f$ is scalar-valued and smooth, then I know it has a manifold gradient. Is there a way I can express $\nabla f$ in a closed-form expression, considering we are on a matrix Lie group? My "intuition" says that it is maybe $\nabla f(g)=gd^2(g,I)\xi$ but I am frankly not sure.